# Is it possible to index a property inside JSON array in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have the following JSON array stored in a table column:

```
Id   ColumnJson
1    [{UserId: 1, Value: 12},{UserId: 2, Value: 20}]
2    [{UserId: 3, Value: 14}]
```

Is it possible to index `UserId` property such that when I search for say for example `UserId = 2`? I don't have to do a table scan.

I know I can create a virtual column index for object properties but I haven't seen the same for JSON array.

Comment: The short answer is no, though Im not as experienced with json outside basic parsing. However, this does point out something I think might be an issue - if you feel the need to index said element it does suggest that maybe storing the json in a column is a bad idea and maybe that should be its own table? Most of the time if you feel like you need the json, its probably a good idea to store in in a more traditional way so that retrieving the data isnt annoying. Also you could always parse into a temp table and index that

Comment: You can create a computed column index, but only on one array index at a time, so if your arrays are a maximum of 5 objects, you would need 5 columns. You cannot put the whole thing in one index like an XML column

Comment: Traditional indexes do not support multiple index nodes per row. You would need a multi-entry index for this, and I doubt SQL Server support this. It's a good question, though, and I would love someone proving me wrong.